# Is it possible to extract Screen Time passcode from macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, password, screen-time

I don't remember my screen time passcode on Big Sur 11.6.8 and I do not want to resort to "forgot your passcode". I have an administrator account on the Mac.

Can I somehow extract this secret code without resetting it?

Answer (score 1):

Very doubtful. Apple systems are more robust than that, otherwise there would be no point having them if they could easily be bypassed.
Wanting to snoop it without resetting just makes it sound like it's being used as a parental control by an Apple ID you don't have control of.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211021